# ctags - generate tags file recursively on OpenBSD

Tags: ctags, openbsd, exuberant-ctags

Although the ctags [manual page for a typical Linux machine](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ctags) says that that the `-R` switch can be used to generate a "tags" file recursively, [the manual page for OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.2/ctags) does not mention how to achieve this. So how do I do this on OpenBSD? Am I missing something? Please help.

I am using Vim 8.0.987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former is "Exuberant Ctags", the latter is "ctags". They are different programs so you can't really expect them to have the same options/features.

If you want Exuberant Ctags, [install it](https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.2/packages/i386/ectags-5.8p3.tgz).